# nodejs + aerospike crashes

Tags: node.js, gdb, aerospike

I am getting the following backtrace from an error that only happens after some subsequent requests to the server:

```
node: ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:171: uv__finish_close: Assertion `handle->flags & UV_CLOSING' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00000030eee32925 in raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64        return INLINE_SYSCALL (tgkill, 3, pid, selftid, sig);
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000030eee32925 in raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00000030eee34105 in abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x00000030eee2ba4e in __assert_fail_base (fmt=<value optimized out>, assertion=0xb37538 "handle->flags & UV_CLOSING", file=0xb374a8 "../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c", line=<value optimized out>, function=<value optimized out>)
    at assert.c:96
#3  0x00000030eee2bb10 in __assert_fail (assertion=0xb37538 "handle->flags & UV_CLOSING", file=0xb374a8 "../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c", line=171, function=0xb37690 "uv__finish_close") at assert.c:105
#4  0x0000000000994bb4 in uv__finish_close (loop=0xe6d840, mode=<value optimized out>) at ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:171
#5  uv__run_closing_handles (loop=0xe6d840, mode=<value optimized out>) at ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:221
#6  uv_run (loop=0xe6d840, mode=<value optimized out>) at ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:319
#7  0x0000000000942132 in node::Start(int, char**) ()
#8  0x00000030eee1ed1d in __libc_start_main (main=0x599710 <main>, argc=2, ubp_av=0x7fffffffdec8, init=<value optimized out>, fini=<value optimized out>, rtld_fini=<value optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdeb8)
    at libc-start.c:226
#9  0x00000000005999f1 in _start ()
```

Any idea why is this happening? I am using [aerospike](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-nodejs) but I am not sure if it is related to the issue.

To reproduce it:

```
gdb --args node /bin/www
> run // until error occurs
> backtrace full
```

Comment: You say subsequent, that doesn't describe the problem very well. I'm guessing that means a lot of requests if so it makes sense, your computer cannot continue to process that amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked on the Aerospike Community Edition user forum [here](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/nodejs-crashing/877/4).

Aerospike made an official release to NPM (Node.js 1.0.38) in April 2015; it fixes this UV assertion segfault when running query in the node.js API.

The user @Daniel reported that his problem is now fixed.